# Trying to get property 'serino' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

I don't want to use "id" to edit the product, I want to use the "serial no" column. But I get the following error:

> Trying to get property 'serino' of non-object

Product.php

```
public function edit($serino)
    {
        $product= DB::select('select * from products where serino=?',[$serino]);
        return view("products/edit",compact("product"));
    }
```

index.blade.php

```
<a href="{{route('products.edit',$product->serino)}}">
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>
</a>
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('products.update',$product->serino)}}" method="post">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    {!! method_field('put') !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$product->name}}" name="name" placeholder="Product Name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" value="{{$product->category}}" name="category" placeholder="Product Category">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Good Work..

Comment: Do you pass $product into idnex.blade.php ?

Comment: You're showing two different views (where you have `$product->serino`), but the code only calls one. How are those views related?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Problem solved.
$product = DB::table('products')->where('serino',$serino)->first();

Answer (score 1):

Your query will return you collection/array of result, no just one Product.
You can use sometihing like this:

`$product = DB::table('products')->where('serino', $serino)->first();`

Comment: Thank you so much. I did as you said and the problem was solved. So how do I do it with Eloquent.

**Example:**

<public function edit($serino)
    {
        $urun = DB::table('urunler')->where('serino',$serino)->first();

        $urun = DB::Product::find($serino);
        return view("urunler/edit",compact("urun"));
    }>